# Cocoapods Library not loaded with multiple frameworks when testing

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Its a little difficult situation but I'll try to explain.

I'm using cocoapods and multiple frameworks in my project. For my simple example there are frameworks:

Project `MegaWolf` with two targets:

- MegaWolf
- MegaWolfTests

Project `Chicken` with two targets:

- Chicken
- ChickenTests

Also there is a `pod 'Food', '2.4'` in cocoapods.

---

`MegaWolf` need to `import Chicken`. So in Frameworks and Libraries in `MegaWolf` target there is `Chicken` with `Do not embed` option.

To `MegaWolfTests` there are two linked things - `MegaWolf.framework` and `Pods_Name.framework` (autogenerated by pods framework).

`Chicken` need to `import Food`. It's making via cocoapods.

In podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!
workspace 'AnyName.xcworkspace'

target 'Chicken' do
  platform :ios, $platformVersion
  project 'Frameworks/Chicken/Chicken.xcodeproj'

  pod 'Food', '2.4'

  target 'ChickenTests' do
    pod 'Food', '2.4'
  end
end
```

When I build frameworks to run everything works.

When I test `ChickenTests` everything works.

But if I test `MegaWolfTests` it's throw an error in runtime: **Library not loaded: @rpath/Food.framework/Food**. But `MegaWolf` and `MegaWolfTests` not using `import Food`. They only `import Chicken`.

I tried to `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` for target 'Chicken'. But I have multiple targets and had to use static many times. The tests started to work well. But when trying to archive there was an error `multiple commands produce Food` that I couldn't resolve. So if there are >1 `linkage => :static` with same pod for different targets - the archive failed.

I've tried `use_modular_headers!` instead of `linkage => :static`. It bring same error in runtime **Library not loaded**.

It seems that chain: MegaWolfTests <- MegaWolf <- Chicken <- Food

I can't understand how to solve that linking problem. Any advice appreciated.